# Saving large videos in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

I am trying to save a large video locally to the photo library using `PHPhotoLibrary` but i notice that it takes a very long time is there any way to get progress or even better to make the process faster

my code:

```swift
    func saveToLibrary(videoURL: URL, complition: @escaping () -> Void) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            guard status == .authorized else { return }
            
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoURL)
            }) { success, error in
                if !success {
                    print("Could not save video to photo library: \( error as Any)")
                } else {
                    complition()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this on a background thread so that your UI doesn't get locked up.

Answer (score 0):

You can first download the video in a temporary local file using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, and then pass the the URL from the that local file to PHPhotoLibrary. This way you can monitor the download progress.

Something like this would work:

```
 // Download the remote URL to a file
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) {
        (tempURL, response, error) in
        // Early exit on error
        guard let tempURL = tempURL else {
            return
        }

        // The file is downloaded in the tempURL we can save it in the library
        saveToLibrary(videoURL: tempURL, complition: {}) 
    }

    // Start the download
    task.resume()

    // Monitor the progress
    let observation = task.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, _ in
  print(progress.fractionCompleted)
}
```